# How to setup www with my freenom subdomain?

Tags: dns, hosting, firebase-hosting, domain-name

I am hosting my website on firebase and for custom domain I am using freenom to get a free domain name. My domain name is [divastra.ml](https://divastra.ml)

And I have successfully connected it with firebase and it is working too. But it is not opening with [www.divastra.ml](http://www.divastra.ml)

It is only opening with [divastra.ml](https://divastra.ml)

In firebase I tried to redirect [www.divastra.ml](http://www.divastra.ml) to divastra.ml. Everything went ok but it is now showing needs setup in status.

I have done 2 process at the same time. First: connected divastra.ml with firebase. Second: redirected [www.divastra.ml](http://www.divastra.ml) to divastra.ml
In both processes previously in status it was written needs setup. After waiting for few hours divastra.ml started working but in the second process(redirecting [www.divastra.ml](http://www.divastra.ml) to divastra.ml) it is still showing needs setup.

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong? The site does open on my computer.

Comment: It seems you're missing an A record for your www subdomain. Check your freenom DNS records again?